# Access component instance in structural directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a structural directive and I need to access instance of a component to which it has been applied to.

There is an open issue with few options / hacks that work for plain directives, but not structural.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277#issuecomment-418478132) ?

Comment: That doesn't work for structural directives. In this case `this.vcRef['_view'].component` contains parent component, not host